# inhomogenous Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this inhomogenous equation.

(*) $y'' + 5y' - 6y = 14e^x$

I solve the Homogenous part and get

$\lambda_1 = 1 $

$ \lambda_2 = -6 $

$Ce^x + De^{-6x}$

Particular solution:

I try here to solve for $y = Ae^x$

Put in the original equation (*) gives me $0$. I have no clue what to do next. Can someone guide me through the last part there? thanks

Comment: Compare your solution of the homogeneous DE to your proposed particular solution to the inhomogeneous DE.

Comment: Sorry, i had wrong equation. it's updated now. As you can see, i have done that and i get 0.

Comment: I don't see a solution to the homogeneous DE.  $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are solutions of the auxiliary equation to the DE, but not of the DE itself.

Comment: it went a bit fast. corrected it. I cant get the exponent right with mathML though. but you understand

Comment: Sorry for not following up sooner. My power went out just as I was replying and wasn't restored until today. Anyway, I see the question's been answered in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $e^x$ is part of your homogeneous solution.  That's why you're getting $0$.  Your particular solution should therefore be in the form $xe^x$.

Let's try solving the equation directly.  I assume you've learned integrating factors.  We have

$$y''+5y'-6y=(y'-y)'+6(y'-y)=14e^x$$
$$e^{6x}(y'-y)'+6e^{6x}(y'-y)=[e^{6x}(y'-y)]'=14e^{7x}$$
$$e^{6x}(y'-y)=2e^{7x}+k_1$$
$$e^{-x}y'-e^{-x}y=(e^{-x}y)'=k_1e^{-7x}+2$$
$$e^{-x}y=k_2e^{-7x}+2x+k_3$$
$$y=k_2e^{-6x}+k_3e^x+2xe^x$$

Comment: Since i'm not really sure how you did it your way, i tried my way and got this:
y = $Axe^x$ 

y' = $Ae^x + Axe^x$

y'' = $2Ae^x + Axe^x$

put in (*)

$(2Ae^x + Axe^x) + 5*(Ae^x + Axe^x) - Axe^x = 14e^x$

=>>
$7Ae^x + 2Axe^x = 14e^x$

and this is how far i get. i can factor out $e^x$ but that doesnt help me get rid of coefficient 7.

Comment: i am then left with $(7A + 2Bx)e^x$ which is close to the answer. but i should not have the 7 there.

Comment: @KimR You forgot the coefficient of $6$.  $Axe^x+5Axe^x-6Axe^x=0$, which should leave you with $7Ae^x=14e^x$.  As for what I did, the substitution $z=y'-y$ transforms this second degree linear differential equation into a first degree.  For $z'+6z=14e^x$, you would use the integrating factor $e^{6x}$.